# Expressão Regular para obter o que há fora dos colchetes

Tags: regex

Texto de exemplo:

```
Itaú [123.456,89]
```

Para obter o que há dentro dos colchetes (incluindo os colchetes) eu usei:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

A dúvida é saber como obter o que está fora?

Imagino que seja uma lista negada, algo simples. Já pesquisei mais de hora e nada.

Se possível, eu queria saber também como obter o que está dentro do colchete, sem incluir os colchetes?

Tudo em uma única expressão, sem prolongar o código [pedaladas].

Texto de exemplo pode ser:

> "Itaú 1 [123.456,89]", "Itaú 2 [543.456,59]", "Banco do Brasil [987.543,21]", etc.

Ou seja, incluem acentos, mais de uma palavra, logo tem espaços e pode ocorrer de começar com números.

Comment: Tem outro exemplo? as linhas sempre iniciam com a-z0-9 seguidas de conchetes?

Comment: Texto de exemplo pode ser "Itaú 1 [123.456,89]", "Itaú 2 [543.456,59]", "Banco do Brasil [987.543,21]", etc. Ou seja, incluem acentos, mais de uma palavra, logo tem espaços e pode ocorrer de começar com números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja funcionando no [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/cS7iP2/3).

Qualquer esclarecimento pergunte.

Pattern:

```
/^([^\]]+) \[([^\]]*)\]/gm
```

Input:

```
Itau [2.265,41]
Bradesco [1.375,21]
Santander Bradesco [784,12]
Caixa 2 []
```

Match:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `Itau`
2.  [6-14]  `2.265,41`
MATCH 2
1.  [16-24] `Bradesco`
2.  [26-34] `1.375,21`
MATCH 3
1.  [36-54] `Santander Bradesco`
2.  [56-62] `784,12`
MATCH 4
1.  [64-71] `Caixa 2`
2.  [73-73] ``
```

Comment: Boa! Mandou bem!

Answer (score 3):

Minha sugestão é usar classes negadas para combinar "tudo o que não for colchete": `[^\[]+` e `[^\]]+`.

Juntando e colocando os grupos ficou: `([^\[]+) (\[([^\]]+)\])`

Exemplo:

```js
var str = 'Itaú 1 [123.456,89]';
var result = str.replace(/([^\[]+) (\[([^\]]+)\])/, 'grupo 1: "$1"<br>grupo 2: "$2"<br>grupo 3: "$3"<br>');
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Gostei! Nada mal!

Comment: Essa fico boa!!

Answer (score 1):

Em javascript, eu faria da seguinte forma:

Para obter somente a palavra `Itaú`:

```
'Itaú [123.456,89]'.replace(/(\[.*\])/g, '');
```

Para obter o que está dentro do colchetes (sem os colchetes):

```
'Itaú [123.456,89]'.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]
```

Comment: Não sou muito bom de `regexp` :(

Comment: Texto de exemplo pode ser "Itaú 1 [123.456,89]", "Itaú 2 [543.456,59]", "Banco do Brasil [987.543,21]", etc. Ou seja, incluem acentos, mais de uma palavra, logo tem espaços e pode ocorrer de começar com números.

Comment: Acho fantástico a mágica das expressões regulares, mas também tenho muita dificuldade de achar o Pattern. Devido a demora, muitas vezes surge a "pedalada" pra chegar na solução com mais linhas, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Veja funcionando no Regex.

https://regex101.com/r/vD2kN9/1

```
$re = "/([A-Za-zÀ-ú0-9]+)([.,]?)/"; 
$str = "Itaú [123.456,89]"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```